# how to scale the graphical display in R when using text function to print a plot of stem and leaf plot using capture output

Tags: r

i am trying to output a stem and leaf plot to a graphical device. It outputs fine to the device but the problem is only a part of the plot shows in the graphic device. How can I scale the plot to fit into the graphical device (window)?

```
library(aplpack)

 plot.new()
 flint <- c(44.6, 25.7, 33.2, 48.3, 39.4, 43.5, 39.8, 40.5, 91.7, 29.3, 
             39.1, 42.5, 49.6, 40.6, 49.1, 41.7, 30.2, 40.0, 31.9, 42.3, 
             47.2, 50.5, 44.1, 45.8)

 chert <- c(25.8, 6.3, 21.3, 20.6, 22.2, 10.5, 18.9, 25.9, 23.8, 22.0, 
             10.6, 16.8, 21.8, 15.8, 16.3, 21.7, 17.9, 13.7, 19.1, 15.2, 
             21.2, 20.2, 10.6, 23.1)
 dev.list()
 dev.set(2)
 tmp <- capture.output(stem.leaf.backback(flint,chert,unit=.1,rule.line="Dixon"))
 text (0,1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj=c(0,1), family='mono')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output to file instead of to screen tends to be more reproducible when it comes controlling the size of the "paper" you draw on. In case you are happy with - for example - a PDF file with the stem plot, something like this works fine:

```
library(aplpack)

flint <- c(44.6, 25.7, 33.2, 48.3, 39.4, 43.5, 39.8, 40.5, 91.7, 29.3, 39.1, 42.5, 49.6, 
           40.6, 49.1, 41.7, 30.2, 40.0, 31.9, 42.3, 47.2, 50.5, 44.1, 45.8)

chert <- c(25.8, 6.3, 21.3, 20.6, 22.2, 10.5, 18.9, 25.9, 23.8, 22.0, 10.6, 16.8, 21.8, 
           15.8, 16.3, 21.7, 17.9, 13.7, 19.1, 15.2, 21.2, 20.2, 10.6, 23.1)
```

You can specify the PDF page width and height (in inches). Say 14" by 7".

```
pdf(file = "stemplot.pdf", width = 14, height = 7)

plot.new()

tmp <- capture.output(stem.leaf.backback(flint, chert, unit = .1, rule.line = "Dixon"))

text(0, 1, paste(tmp, collapse='\n'), adj = c(0,1), family = 'mono')

dev.off()
```

Of course we changed the page size instead of scaling the plot, so it is not exactly what you originally asked...

In case output to file is acceptable, here are
[10 tips for making your R graphics look their best](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/01/10-tips-for-making-your-r-graphics-look-their-best.html).